# Can a car with a B or C sticker drive in central Madrid if it does not park on the street?

Tags: automobiles, madrid

Madrid has Low Emission Zones (Zonas de Bajas Emisiones (ZBE)) where cars are restricted in where they can drive depending on how polluting they are (mainly in terms of Greenhouse Gas emissions). B and C classification is for middlingly polluting cars. They are currently allowed into the central zone but are restricted in where they can park.

They can not park on the street (in parking bays). They can park in City-run underground parkings.

It's not at all clear from what I have read if they can park anywhere else. In the parking of a store, supermarket, office or factory? In the grounds of someone else's private house (that you might be visiting for example)?

Also, can you just drive through the zone and not park at all?

I would welcome more precise information than what I can glean from official web sites.

Comment: That's kinda funny. "Yes, you can drive your more polluting car into the city, but you can't park it in the open, instead you must drive it underground where all the pollutants are captured and held due to minimal natural air circulation, requiring _more_ energy to pump the fumes out and choking the people who are walking to/from their cars."